# LTemplate C++ code seems to run faster than the same code compiled outside of Mathematica

Tags: librarylink, c++

I am slightly puzzled by now and am not able to figure out what's going on inside of LibraryLink (used by LTemplate) to justify what I recognized:

I have C++ code that is way too extensive to be shown here, but that mainly only consists of if-else-constructs and `*` and `+` many terms. If I arrange my data as Mathematica Lists and use `LTemplate` which uses `LibraryLink` the data is handled as `IntTensorRef` and `RealTensorRef`. The `LTemplate` code is compiled by `clang` and — when executed in Mathematica — runs orders of magnitude faster than when I compile the C++ code directly with the same compiler and the same compiler options and replace `IntTensorRef` and `RealTensorRef` by pure `C` arrays.

Since my code will run on `HPC` clusters, using Mathematica is unfortunately not an option, so I am forced to use C++. As I have no idea what the underlying data structures are doing my question is: How do `IntTensorRef` and `RealTensorRef` achieve such a performance boost over a pure `C` array? Do they prefetch? Do they increase the number of cache hits and lower cache misses?

Comment: For those unfamiliar with LTemplate, `IntTensorRef` and `RealTensorRef` just wrap an `MTensor` of integer or real type.

Comment: I have no idea why this would be the case (to be frank, I am quite skeptical that the speed difference is due to using Mathematica).  MTensor simply stores data contiguously. Are you sure that something doesn't go wrong when using Mathematica that prevents your C++ code from running at all? Some silent failure?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your kind answer. And yes, I am sceptical as well considering the speed differences. There is no doubt that the C++ code is indeed run within Mathematica since the calculations rely on output generated by this code. The C++ code (run itself) and the MMA code both produce the same output - with the only difference being time. Since C arrays should be contiguously stored as well the problem must lay somewhere different. Though, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: I hoped for some clever prefetching done in the internals of Mathematica (which I clearly do not do with C arrays) but if you are right and `MTensor` is no highly clever data structure I might have to rethink my problem as it can not be connected to the pure data structure exchange.

Comment: @Szabolcs can `LTemplate` hook in to Mathematica's automatic threading/parallelization processes? That's the only thing I can think of that'd make Mathematica actually work faster. Or maybe it finds a way to remove some unnecessary casts that ended up being really expensive somehow.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this is not due to a simple mistake on the OP's part. (I made such a mistake myself today and banged my head against the wall for an hour trying to figure out why a function is faster than a subroutine it calls. Well, of course it was not faster.)